# Get mutual_friends attending an Event on Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have an `event id` and I want to get all mutual_friends attending an Events. Currently I just got and attending people from graph API. Like the following

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/event-id/?fields=attending
```

But how I can filter mutual friends?

Comment: Get the persons friends and compare it to people attending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, now I finally got my own answer. As @We0 comment I try to get my own mutual friends and I try to got event attend list using `event_id`. And I merge with `array_search` function. And the following is my code...

```
function getCommonFriend($event_id)
{
    //Setup Facebook Configuration
    $facebook                   = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));

    //If there is no common friends so there will be 0
    $commmon_friends = 0;

    //Get Attending Friends
    $event_attending            = $facebook->api('v2.1/' .$event_id . '?fields=attending');
    $event_attending_friends    = $event_attending['attending']['data'];

    $events_attending_friends_id = array();

    foreach ($event_attending_friends as $key => $value) {
        $events_attending_friends_id['id']{$key} = $value['id'];
    }

    //Get Own Mutual Friends
    $me                         = $facebook->api('v2.1/me?fields=context');
    $my_mutual_friends          = $me['context']['mutual_friends']['data'];

    foreach ($my_mutual_friends as $key => $value) {
        $my_mutual_friends_id = $value['id'];
        $get_commmon_friends = array_search($my_mutual_friends_id, $events_attending_friends_id['id']);
        if (!empty($get_commmon_friends)) {
            $commmon_friends ++;
        }
    }



    return $commmon_friends;
}
```